# TURLEncoding.Base64.Encode adds Linebreak?

Tags: delphi, base64

It seems that `URLEncoding.Base64.Encode` adds a linebreak in long strings. Can I turn that off somehow? I didnt find any properties for that...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is `TBase64Encoding.Create(CharsPerLine: Integer)` constructor. When `CharsPerLine` <= 0, then encoder will stop to add line breaks. In this case encoder must be created and destroyed explicitly.